# XMLHttpRequest authentication not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, authentication, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to send an authenticated (basic authentication) POST request using XMLHttpRequest. It works in chrome and IE, but Firefox systematically returns an error 401 asking for login credentials. When I enter them the request works normally. Furthermore, I also do GET requests using the same authentication, and they work on all browsers (including Firefox).
I use JQuery 1.7, but I have also tried without it with the same results.
Here is the code I use:

```
$.ajax({
            url: [relative path],
            type: "POST",
            username: user_id,
            password: token,
            data : dataText,
            success: function(data){
                if(data == null) alert('Error: could not send message');
                else
                    handleUpdate(data);
            }
    });
```

or without JQuery:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open("POST", [relative path], false, user_id, token);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(xhr.readyState == 4 && (xhr.status == 200 || xhr.status == 0)) {
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
        }
    }
    xhr.send(dataText);
```

In both cases, Firebug shows the requests to be of this form:
    http://user:password@absolute_url (the absolute url belonging to the same domain as the website)

Any idea of what I could be doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try to first send a request with credentials you know to be invalid:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", [relative path], false, "username_you_know_is_wrong", "any_string");
xhr.send(dataText);
```

Then run your block of code above.